# Why does my JavaScript window handle become invalid?

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have the following two HTML files. The first HTML provides two buttons to open and close a child webapp. The second HTML provides a user with a button to display a PDF.

The first HTML is started and the user clicks on 'Open Child'. If the user does NOT click 'Display PDF', in the child window, the parent window can close the child window when 'Close Child' is clicked. If the user clicks on 'Display PDF', in the child window, the parent window cannot close the child window when 'Close Child' is clicked. I assume that since the parent window has the reference to the child window it should be able to close the child window under all circumstances. Is there a way to close a child and all of it's child windows from the parent window?

```
HTML 1
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var childHandle = null;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Open Child" onclick="childHandle = window.open('windowOpenTestChild.html', '_blank', 'location=0');">
  <input type="button" value="Close Child" onclick="if(childHandle !== null) { childHandle.close(); }">
</body>
</html>

HTML 2
<html>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Display PDF" onclick="window.open('roboRIO Overview.pdf', '_self');">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of writing code inside on inline event handlers.

Comment: Reason you are using `_self`? You want to open up the PDF in the current window? My guess that is killing the reference.

Comment: I wrote it inline to simplify it for the post. The child window is client code, I cant change it. Yes, the client opens the PDF in the child window as described. I am trying to understand why the reference is no longer valid and any workarounds.

Comment: Ah, I misread your code. I thought it was one document. The issue is probably the PDF takes over the window and browser will not allow you to interact with it any more.